# Templates and lose of information

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, c++11

I created a matrix class:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols);
    Matrix(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols, const T& value);

    void fill(const T& value);
    size_t n_rows() const;
    size_t n_cols() const;

    void print(std::ostream& out) const;

    T& operator()(size_t row_index, size_t col_index);
    T operator()(size_t row_index, size_t col_index) const;
    bool operator==(const Matrix<T>& matrix) const;
    bool operator!=(const Matrix<T>& matrix) const;
    Matrix<T>& operator+=(const Matrix<T>& matrix);
    Matrix<T>& operator-=(const Matrix<T>& matrix);
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& matrix) const;
    Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T>& matrix) const;
    Matrix<T>& operator*=(const T& value);
    Matrix<T>& operator*=(const Matrix<T>& matrix);
    Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& matrix) const;

private:
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

Now I want to enable operations between matrix of different types, for example:

```
Matrix<int> matrix_i(3,3,1); // 3x3 matrix filled with 1
Matrix<double> matrix_d(3,3,1.1); // 3x3 matrix filled with 1.1

std::cout << matrix_i * matrix_d << std::endl;
```

I thought to do like this (is the right way?):

```
template<typename T> // Type of the class instantiation
template<typename S>
Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<S>& matrix)
{
   // Code
}
```

I think this will work fine if I multiply a double matrix with an integer matrix: I will obtain a new double matrix. The problem is that if I multiply an integer matrix with a double matrix I will lose some information, because the matrix I obtain will be an integer matrix... Right? How can I fix this behave?

```
std::cout << matrix_d * matrix_i << std::endl; // Works: I obtain a 3x3 matrix full of 1.1
std::cout << matrix_i * matrix_d << std::endl; // Doesn't work: I obtain a 3x3 matrix full of 1 instead of 1.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want, you will need to offer an `operator*` that returns a `Matrix<X>` where `X` is the type with the largest range/greatest precision.

If you have a C++11 compiler at hand, you could use:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator*( Matrix<T> const & lhs, Matrix<U> const & rhs) 
     -> Matrix< delctype( lhs(0,0) * rhs(0,0) ) >
{
   Matrix< delctype( lhs(0,0) * rhs(0,0) ) > result( lhs );
   result *= rhs;
   return result;
}
```

Assuming that you have `operator*=` implemented as a template that allows multiplications with other instantiations of `Matrix<T>` and that you have a conversion constructor.

Comment: I have C++ compiler (GCC 4.7). The auto keyword is the only way? What is a conversion constructor? Can you explain me the third line? I don't get it... Thank you.

Comment: @R.M.: C++11 is no the only way, but it is the simplest. g++4.7 should support the syntax if you pass in `-std=c++11`. The `auto` together with the `-> ...` are called *trailing return type*, and are a way of postponing the definition of the return type until the arguments to the function are in context (so that `lhs` and `rhs` can be used inside the `decltype` expression)

Comment: @R.M. A *conversion constructor* (I don't think the standard calls them so, but I thought this would be understood) would be a constructor that takes an argument of a different type, effectively performing a *type conversion*. In C++03 you could define a type trait that takes two types and yields the promoted type (say `int,int`->`int`, `int,double`->`double`) and use that trait in the return type: `template <typename T, typename U> Matrix< typename promoted<T,U>::type > operator*( Matrix<T> const&, Matrix<U> const& )`.